# Rewriting urls with htaccess and PHP

Tags: .htaccess, url

I'm trying to rewrite the following URL

```
www.domain.com/?part=messages
```

to:

```
www.domain.com/messages
```

I've folowed some .htaccess tutorials but I couldn't. How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you looked at the Rewrite Engine? (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) And what do you mean with "I couldn't", what do you already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple rule actually:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /?part=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Thanks, works fine (the option I had before too, the problem was that I was testing it the wrong way).

Comment: @anubhava I have not learnt regex , what would a rewriterule look like  to convert www.foo.com/user.php?id=111 to www.foo.com/john.smith

Comment: That cannot be done in rewrite rules since a different user will different username.