# How can Rewrite URL in PHP

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I just wanted to know how i can customize my website's URLs in PHP.

**For Example:**

`http://something.com/home/index.php?id=5`

TO

`http://something.com/home/t-shirts`

Please Tell me the efficient way to doing this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to re-write it the other way around?

Comment: Use `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` however what `CompuChip` said makes sense. --^

Comment: That's about the most asked question ever. What did you research, what have you tried?

Comment: ^-- Ah, so it wins the prize then --^

Comment: Simply rewrite your URL http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewriting urls with htaccess and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605890/rewriting-urls-with-htaccess-and-php)

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that in PHP.
Your webserver needs to do it, if you are using Apache webserver, use the rewrite functionality.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: and if by any chance you are on IIS - http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example what you could put in your .HTAccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/t-shirts$ /home/index.php?id=5 [L]
```

Also here is a nice little [mod rewrite generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/) to help you create your .HTAccess file.

Comment: thanks but when i try this, and run file with old url it does not modified to the new url

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|less|json|JPG|ico|html)$ index.php
```

In your index.php

```
$url=strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url_array=explode("/",$url);
array_shift($url_array); //the first one is empty anyway
```

You can now access to

- **home** with **$url_array[0]**
- **t-shirts** with **$url_array[1]**